# ASP.NET - VB.NET - Getting data from MS-Access database where Username =?

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, ms-access, data-retrieval

I'm using Web Developer 2010, ASP.NET with the VB.NET programming language and a MS-Access database (.mdb).

What I want to do is get all the data from a table called User (i.e. all the columns) where Username = ***_*___**, and then put the values in from the fields into text boxes so they can be edited. This is to make a 'My Account' page so that a user viewing the website can change his address, password etc.

I'm stuck at getting the data from the fields for each specific username.

What I've done so far is this, but doesn't work:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data

Partial Class Account
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


        Dim tUsername As String = Session("Username")
        Dim tPassword As String = Session("Password")

        Dim conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Brian\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\PetLandia\App_Data\db.mdb")
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT [Email], [CustomerName], [CustomerSurname], [Address], [Country], [TelNo], [Username], [Password] FROM [User] WHERE Username=?", conn)

        DataSet(dst = New DataSet)

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", tUsername)

        conn.Open()

        Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

        If (reader.Read()) Then

            lblName.Text = reader.GetValue(4).ToString
            lblSurname.Text = reader.GetValue(5).ToString
            lblUsername.Text = reader.GetValue(9).ToString
            txtAddress.Text = reader.GetValue(6).ToString
            txtCountry.Text = reader.GetValue(7).ToString
            txtEmail.Text = reader.GetValue(2).ToString

            conn.Close()

        End If





    End Sub


End Class
```

Error message:

```
Parameter ?_1 has no default value.
```

at

`Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader`

Any help ?

Comment: What error message/evidence are you getting that indicates it isn't working?

Comment: RThomas: Updated main question with error message

Comment: Can you verify that tUsername has a value (is not null or undefined).  Setting it equal to a session variable requires that the session be there to give it something.

Comment: @RThomas: It has a value, because I had another problem and I fixed it. I get a new error:  'Index was outside the bounds of the array.' at 'lblUsername.Text = reader.GetValue(9).ToString'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your index numbers are not lining up with your query statement.

Try

```
        lblName.Text = reader.GetValue(2).ToString 
        lblSurname.Text = reader.GetValue(3).ToString 
        lblUsername.Text = reader.GetValue(7).ToString 
        txtAddress.Text = reader.GetValue(4).ToString 
        txtCountry.Text = reader.GetValue(5).ToString 
        txtEmail.Text = reader.GetValue(0).ToString
```

Comment: just a question, how can I get the index value of each column from Ms-Access

Comment: The index used by GetValue is controlled by your select statement.  (fyi, they're also zero based).  So whatever columns your select statement specifies are what those indexes represent.  Example: select name, email results in 0 = name, 1 = email.  If instead you did select email, name then 0 = email, 1 = name.

Answer (score 3):

you need to give parameter as `@Username` not like `?`

```
 Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT [Email], [CustomerName], [CustomerSurname], [Address], [Country], [TelNo], [Username], [Password] FROM [User] WHERE Username=@Username", conn)
```

Use `Using` statement when you deal with connection as below

```
Dim queryString As String = "SELECT OrderID, CustomerID FROM Orders"
Using connection As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
    Dim command As New OleDbCommand(queryString, connection)

    connection.Open()

    Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
    While reader.Read()
        Console.WriteLine(reader.GetInt32(0).ToString() + ", " _
           + reader.GetString(1))
    End While

    ' always call Close when done reading.
    reader.Close()
End Using
```

And Also make sure `reader.GetValue(Index)` index always lower than select column count.

Comment: I get this error message: 'Parameter @Username has no default value.'

Comment: Sorry, that was another problem which i fixed. Problem was: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.' at 'lblUsername.Text = reader.GetValue(9).ToString'